# Compare Calendar Date To Get Past Objects

Tags: java

I have the Calendar object which is set to PST timezone. What I am doing for comparison.

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar Object In PST
Calendar cal2 = Calendar Object In PST

if(cal1.after(cal2)){
  // Add object to future event list
} else {
  // Add object to past event list
}
```

Now, this comparison is based on the timestamp. So if two events are on same date, I can see after some hours both moved in past event list. But I want the object to be added in past event list only if date has be passed. Any solution?

Comment: get Date() object from calendar using cal.getTime()

Answer (score 0):

You can use [org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils#truncate(java.util.Calendar, int)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html#truncate-java.util.Calendar-int-) to remove time from your calendar and just check for dates